# getHeadline that returns a newspaper headline, which we'll know based on the location and the superhero present

Tags: javascript

Given two parameters, a superhero and a city, write a function called headline that returns a newspaper headline if (and only if) our city gets saved — which we'll know based on the location and the superhero present.

In this DC/Marvel comics world, here is who we have:

```
Three superheros: Superman, Batman, Spiderman,
Three aliases: Clark Kent, Bruce Wayne, and Peter Parker,
And three locations: Metropolis, Gotham City, and New York City.
```

We also know that each alias corresponds to a particular superhero, so...

```
The alias Clark Kent belongs to Superman,
Bruce Wayne belongs to Batman,
and Peter Parker belongs to Spiderman.
```

And we know that each superhero is located in a different city...

```
Superman oversees Metropolis.
Batman patrols Gotham City.
Spiderman keeps New York City safe.
```

To find out if the city is saved, determine if the superhero provided is in their respective city. And if so, return a headline that look like the following:

```
__________, living under the alias of __________, saved the city of __________!
```

If the right superhero isn't present in the right city, the city isn't saved, and the function should return an empty string ('').

```js
function getHeadline(superhero, city) {
   var alias = '';
  if (superhero !== 'Superman' && city !== 'Metropolis') {
    console.log('');
  } else if (superhero !== 'Batman' && city !== 'Gotham City') {
    console.log('2');
  } else if (superhero !== 'Spiderman' && city !== 'New York City') {
    console.log('3');
  } else {
    if (superhero === 'Superman' && city === 'Metropolis') {
      alias = 'Clark Kent';
    } else if (superhero === 'Batman' && city === 'Gotham City'){
      alias = 'Bruce Wayne';
    } else if (superhero === 'Spiderman' && city === 'New York City'){
      alias = "Peter Parker";
    } else{
      return superhero +", living under the alias of "+ alias +" ,saved the city of "+ city + "!";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd create a global object (outside the function):
`superheros={
  name: {
    alias:...,
    city:...
  },
...the other two...
}`, 
and then check in the function like this:
`if(superheros[superhero].city==city) msg=superhero+" "+superheros[superhero].alias+" "+city;
else msg="";`.

Comment: @iAmOren I almost suggested this too - but it seems very "intro to programming", so thought objects may be overcomplicating!

Comment: @DannyBattison, it's good if the homework will develop into a project...

Comment: `if (superhero !== 'Superman' && city !== 'Metropolis')` is `true` when superhero is Spiderman and city is New York (City), for example.
Perhaps: `if (superhero == 'Superman' && city !== 'Metropolis')`?
See @DannyBattison's suggested solution in his answer below.

Comment: Also, your last `else` shouldn't be:  Once you've set the `alias` through `if`-`else`s, send the message.
`if(...) {alias...} else if(...) {alias...} else if(...) {alias}; return "...";`.
You should only get to this set of `if`-`else`s if you haven't `return`ed an empty string - following `if(sh==".." && c!="..")`.

Answer (score 1):

You've overcomplicated matters somewhat here.  We don't need anywhere near as many cases as you currently have, so we can strip it down a bit.  What we essentially need to do is:

1. Match superhero and city
2. a. If match: set alias
   b. If no match: return empty string
3. Return formatted string

```js
function getHeadline(superhero, city) {
  var alias = '';
  if (superhero === 'Superman' && city === 'Metropolis') {
    alias = 'Clark Kent';
  } else if (superhero === 'Batman' && city === 'Gotham City'){
    alias = 'Bruce Wayne';
  } else if (superhero === 'Spiderman' && city === 'New York City'){
    alias = 'Peter Parker';
  } else {
    return '';
  }
  
  return superhero + ', living under the alias of ' + alias + ', saved the city of ' + city + '!';
}

console.log("('Superman', 'Metropolis'):\n", getHeadline('Superman', 'Metropolis'));
console.log("('Superman', 'New York'):\n", getHeadline('Superman', 'New York'));
```

You also had a mix of single and double quotes - I've switched to single.  Consistency is key!

One could also argue that we could merge that second `if` into the if/else, though

Comment: Nice!
Personally, I prefer double-quotes for Strings, and single for Chars (JavaScript makes no distinction - just from previous languages and habit...)

Comment: Found the C guy ;)

Comment: How about the Basic guy?  Assembler?  :)
I'm trying to edit your answer to turn it into a snippet, but "Suggested edit queue is full"...

Comment: I've edited your answer into a snippet + showed passed data in log + log of a failed match.
Can you wait until it's approved/denied, and then:
Change "1" to "match superhero and city -> set alias",
Change "2" to "if no match found -> return empty string".
- because of your edit...
Or, can I do it?
Not to cross wires... :)
I've up-voted your answer, by the way.

Comment: Go for it - I think the 1/2/3 was just OP debugging though, can't see anything in his requirements about it.  I'm fairly new to posting on StackOverflow so still figuring out what's going on :) (PS... ugh, assembler)